# Build failed with error "missing assembly or using directive"

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5, azure-devops

I'm setting up an on-premise TFS build server (2015) with TFS-Online (visualstudio.com) and Visual Studio 2015. I would like to build an ASP.NET 4.5 web project. The TFS-Online build works but I still have problems to fix the on-premise build host. The MSBuild-Log offers the following issues (I'm using a German Windows Server 2012 R2):

```
Für SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.5,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
Berücksichtigte Speicherorte von AssemblyFoldersEx.
Für SearchPath "{AssemblyFolders}".
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.winmd wurde berücksichtigt, war jedoch nicht vorhanden.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.dll wurde berücksichtigt, war jedoch nicht vorhanden.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.exe wurde berücksichtigt, war jedoch nicht vorhanden.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.winmd wurde berücksichtigt, war jedoch nicht vorhanden.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.dll wurde berücksichtigt, war jedoch nicht vorhanden.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.exe wurde berücksichtigt, war jedoch nicht vorhanden.
```

... et cetera, et cetera (nearly every assembly is missing).

I tried the following:

- I installed Visual Studio 2015 on the build machine.
- In my XAML-build-definition, I pass the following argument to force MSBuild to use Visual Studio 2015: **/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0**
- I modified the *.csproj-File (https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore)

Why looks MSBuild into the Microsoft SQL Server folder for Newtonsoft.Json assemblies?
Do you have an idea how I can bring the TFS build to work?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some reason that you are using the legacy xaml build agent? You should use the 2015 agents instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting the packages folder and referring to the following manual: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build